# Changing structure of html menu using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

CMS, that I am using, generates such a code for menu:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">second level menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">third level menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">third level menu</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">second level menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">third level menu</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

I would like to change the way of displaying the third level menu. Is it possible to change this code using javascript into:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">second level menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">third level menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="">third level menu</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">second level menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">third level menu</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
</ul>
...
```

Comment: I can't edit the original code of menu in this cms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to differentiate `li` elements, so you can identify then, which should be first or next level elements.  Setting [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), I think is a not "so much bad solution".

Btw, below is only a boilerplate code, and will work verily for given structure. You need to grasp the logic - so you can apply it to other problems.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li data-level="2"><a href="">second level menu</a></li>
    <li data-level="3"><a href="">third level menu</a></li>
    <li data-level="3"><a href="">third level menu</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li data-level="2"><a href="">second level menu</a></li>
    <li data-level="3"><a href="">third level menu</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var uls = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
  for(var i=0; i<uls.length; i++) {
    var children = uls[i].querySelectorAll("li");
    var _children = Array.from(children).filter(e=> e.dataset.level == "3");
    if (_children.length > 0) {
      var newul = document.createElement("ul");
      _children.map(e=>newul.appendChild(e));
      uls[i].appendChild(newul);
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @marmeladze!